# How to get BACKLOG of listening socket

Tags: linux, performance, tcp, nginx, kernel

I have a listening socket on port 80 on ubuntu linux.

```
tcp    0  0 0.0.0.0:80      0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  12248/nginx
```

Is there any way to get backlog value of that socket (backlog value that was sent to listen() call)?

I know that I could view the nginx configuration but configuration file could be changed without reloading nginx with new configuration, so the backlog argument in configuration and in actual LISTEN call could be different.

Answer (score 31):

`ss -lt` gives this value in the Send-Q column.

Comment: This shows what the max value is, is there a way to see how many requests are currently queued in the backlog on the socket?

Comment: Schneems, you should be able to see that in the other column (Recv-Q). For instance, create a server that listens on a socket but never accepts. If you `telnet` four times and leave that running in the background, you should see `Recv-Q` with a value of 4.

Comment: Note that the value that you see in `Send-Q` (the effective backlog size for such socket) might be different from the value set by the user in the `listen(2)` syscall. That's because Linux will make use of `/proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn` as a ceiling and change the backlog value based on that (see `net/socket.c#sys_listen`: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/net/socket.c#L1479)

Comment: @CiroCosta That's the current size, not the maximum size. It doesn't provide the 'backlog value of that socket (backlog value that was sent to `listen()` call)', which is what was asked for.

Comment: Is there a way I can change the running server backlog value in c code. Some system call or kernel hook or ioctl or something. Or the only solution is to close socket and start listening again which I think probably used in server I may be wrong

Answer (score -1):

id use the current backlog information to manage the number of connections received BECAUSE I can respond to the incoming connections and tell the sender to modify their connection interval, thus reducing (or increasing) load. I cannot control how many incoming connections I get but I can control how frequently they connect, hence keeping the backlog down and preventing timeouts on incoming connections.

in my case this happens to be a feature of the incoming connection source firmware, so it might be unique to my situation and not relevant to others.

Answer (score -6):

There is no standard TCP API for getting the backlog. There is also no reason to need it. You created the socket, you put it into listen state, you should know what backlog you specified. Th system is entitled to adjust it up or down, but even then there is nothing useful you can do you with that information in your application.

Comment: There is nothing useful to do with that information, as there was _No point on having more than 640K of RAM_.

Comment: @Chucky The fact is that in the 35-ish years since the BSD Sockets API was designed nobody has seen fit to add such a function, which indicates that no use fort has been found. If you have a counterexample please provide it. Merely juxtaposing two unrelated issues doesn't actually consisting a logical argument, but this particular juxtaposition is poorly chosen for your purpose. The 640k mistake was recognized and addressed within a few years. The lack of a listen backlog API has never been addressed at all, which shows that generations of TCP/IP implementors agree with me.

Comment: Error messaging to the operator is one reason.

Showing that the backlog is being hit is another, for exposing load status.

Comment: @aredridel The question is about 'the backlg value that was set in the `lsten()` call', not about its current occupancy, and it's hard to see what they operator can do with, or about, that information.